# Find files that match multiple criteria and copy them to a folder

Tags: command-line

I'm new to this forum and hope someone will be able to help me.

I'm MacOS user.

I have a **Folder A** with about 5000 files. They are named as described below:

Booking #0001 - PLACED
Booking #0001 - PREPAID
Booking #0001 - PAID
Booking #0002 - PLACED
Booking #0002 - CANCELLED
Booking #0003 - PLACED
Booking #0003 - PREPAID
Booking #0003 - PAID
Booking #0004 - PLACED
Booking #0004 - PREPAID
Booking #0004 - PAID
Booking #0005 - PLACED
Booking #0005 - PREPAID
Booking #0005 - PAID
Booking #0006 - PLACED
Booking #0006 - CANCELLED
...
Booking #NNNN - PLACED

I have a list of booking numbers (0002, 0007, 0012, 0899, ..., NNNN) and I need files that contain those numbers (no matter if they are -PLACED, -PAID, or -CANCELLED) be copied to **Folder B**.

Doing that manually will require hundreds of hours and mistakes are very possible.

I'm looking for a solution to do that with terminal command.

I would very much appreciate a step-by-step guidance if that requires more than just one terminal command, or any other help.

Comment: In what form is the "list of booking numbers"?  Is it a file with one number per line?  Something else?

Comment: "I'm MacOS user." <--You should post this question on unix.stackexchange.com.  This site is for Ubuntu and Macs are not Ubuntu.

Comment: list of booking number is currently in excel table format, so I can easily make it a .txt file with one number per line

Comment: it needed I can make them be in a row separated by what ever symbol.

Comment: I can also put "-o -iname" or any other code/text between the booking numbers

Answer (score 2):

If the numbers are one-per-line in file `numbers`, try:

```
while read -r num; do mv *"$num"* /path/to/folder2; done <numbers
```

#### Example

Let's start in a directory with these files:

```
$ ls
Booking #0001 - PAID       Booking #0002 - PLACED   Booking #0004 - PAID     Booking #0005 - PLACED     numbers
Booking #0001 - PLACED     Booking #0003 - PAID     Booking #0004 - PLACED   Booking #0005 - PREPAID
Booking #0001 - PREPAID    Booking #0003 - PLACED   Booking #0004 - PREPAID  Booking #0006 - CANCELLED
Booking #0002 - CANCELLED  Booking #0003 - PREPAID  Booking #0005 - PAID     Booking #0006 - PLACED
```

And folder2 is empty:

```
$ ls ../folder2
$
```

File `numbers` looks like:

```
$ cat numbers
0002
0004
```

Now, run our command:

```
$ while read -r num; do mv *"$num"* ../folder2; done <numbers
```

Afterward, our current directory has only these files:

```
$ ls
Booking #0001 - PAID     Booking #0003 - PAID     Booking #0005 - PAID     Booking #0006 - CANCELLED
Booking #0001 - PLACED   Booking #0003 - PLACED   Booking #0005 - PLACED   Booking #0006 - PLACED
Booking #0001 - PREPAID  Booking #0003 - PREPAID  Booking #0005 - PREPAID  numbers
```

And folder2 now has these files:

```
$ ls ../folder2
Booking #0002 - CANCELLED  Booking #0002 - PLACED  Booking #0004 - PAID  Booking #0004 - PLACED  Booking #0004 - PREPAID
```

Comment: John, thank you very much, I'm going to test it immediately!

Comment: Sorry if my questions look too stupid, but I need to ask them to make sure I do everything correct:

1). My folder2 is located here: ⁨Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨Users⁩ ▸ ⁨Mikhail ▸ ⁨Documents⁩ ▸ Folder2
Would it be correct to indicate path to folder2 like this:
/Users/Mikhail/Documents/Folder2

2). $ ls

and 

$ ls ../folder2
$ 

are these commands to run?

3). where should I place numbers file? should it be .txt file?

Comment: The `$` is supposed to represent the prompt on the command line.  Don't type it.  The command `ls` shows the list of file.  For example, to see if your path is correct, run `ls /Users/Mikhail/Documents/Folder2` and see if the correct files show up in the output.  Put the numbers file in FolderA and you should be in FolderA when you start the commands.

Comment: ls /Users/MikhailMaletkin/Documents/Folder1 works perfectly it shows list of all files! I'm on the right way!

Comment: Do I understand correct: I put Folder2 inside Filder1?

Comment: numbers.txt I also put inside Folder1?

Comment: if placing both numbers.txt file and Folder2 inside Folder1 is correct, than I try this command:

Comment: $ while read -r num; do mv *"$num"* ../Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/Folder1/Folder2; done <numbers

Comment: and get this error:

Comment: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'

Comment: Johh, this is what I get at the moment:

Comment: Mikhails-iMac:~ mikhailmaletkin$ while read -r num; do mv *"$num"* ../Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/Folder1/Folder2; done <numbers

Comment: -bash: numbers: No such file or directory

Comment: I'm trying to move numbers from folder1 to folder2 back, renaming number to numbers.txt - still "No such file or directory"

Comment: John, I was trying to understand why suggested command doesn't work. We show where to move file, but do we show where to take it from??

Comment: If the command `$ while read -r num; do mv "$num" ../Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/Folder1/Folder2; done <numbers` generates the error message `unexpected token 'do' `, that means that you typed the `$`.  As I explained earlier, the `$` is supposed to indicate a prompt.  It is not something that you type.  Do __not__ type the `$`.

Comment: You told me that `ls /Users/Mikhail/Documents/Folder2` works.  That means that the directory name is `/Users/Mikhail/Documents/Folder2`.   That being the case, when the directory name is needed, use that.  Don't use `../Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/Folder1/Folder2` because that means something else.

Comment: If you use the name `numbers` in the command, the file needs to be named `numbers`.   If you want the file to be named `numbers.txt` then you need to use `numbers.txt` in the command.  They have to be consistent.

Comment: John, thanks for coming back to me. I really appreciate your help. I left my office and proceed on my laptop that is why path is slightly different.
ls /Users/MikhailMaletkin/Documents/Folder1 shows the folder contents as it should.
cat /Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/folder1/numbers.txt returns file contents as it should.
Folder2 is placed inside Folder1.
$ while read -r num; do mv *"$num"* ../Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/folder1/folder2; done <numbers.txt returns "-bash: numbers.txt: No such file or directory"
If you have any ideas of what else can I try, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Maybe replacing "<numbers.txt" with "</Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/folder1/numbers.txt"?

Comment: Yes, that sounds good.  First run `ls /Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/folder1/numbers.txt`.  If that shows file name and no error, then you have the right path.  Then, as you suggest,  use `</Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/folder1/numbers.txt`.  Good luck.

Comment: 1) it showed file name and no errorr

Comment: 2). As you suggested I used full address of numbers.txt and got a little further, but still not success:

Comment: mv: rename *1285* to ../Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/folder1/folder2: No such file or directory
mv: rename *1295* to ../Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/folder1/folder2: No such file or directory
mv: rename *1296* to ../Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/folder1/folder2: No such file or directory

Comment: (there are three numbers in numbers.txt file)

Comment: this means it understands the </Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/folder1/numbers.txt address, but gets stuck at some other step.

Comment: ```mv: rename *1285* to ../Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/folder1/folder2: No such file or directory
mv: rename *1295* to ../Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/folder1/folder2: No such file or directory
mv: rename *1296* to ../Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/folder1/folder2: No such file or directory```

Comment: We discussed this before.  If `/Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/folder1/folder2` is the right path (you say you verified it with `ls`), then __use that path__.  do __not__ use `../Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/folder1/folder2` because that means something else.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Corrected. I do this: ```while read -r num; do mv *"$num"* /Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/folder1/folder2; done </Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/folder1/numbers.txt```

Comment: get this: ```mv: rename *1285* to /Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/folder1/folder2/*1285*: No such file or directory
mv: rename *1295* to /Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/folder1/folder2/*1295*: No such file or directory
mv: rename *1296* to /Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/folder1/folder2/*1296*: No such file or directory```

Comment: That means that there are no files in the current directory numbered 1285, 1295, or 1296.  Did you `cd` into folder1 before running the command?

Comment: In **folder1** there are among other files: "Booking #1285", "Booking #1285 - CANCELLED" and I also place there pure "1285" - still same result.

Comment: __Did you `cd` into folder1 before running the command?__

Comment: What is **cd into folder1**?

Comment: Do you mean if I copied files into **folder1**? Yes I did.

Comment: Just googled what you mean.... ```cd /Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/folder1``` is that what needed?

Comment: Yes.  Run `cd /Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/folder1` __before__ running the `while` command.  The shell has a _current directory_.  The command needs the _current directory_ to be folder1.  `cd` means "change directory".  Before running the `while` command run `cd /Users/mikhailmaletkin/Documents/folder1`.  Then run `pwd` and verify that you are in folder1.

Comment: Got it!
Thanks for trying to help me. I was deeply touched with your readiness to help and your patience in teaching me all the basics.